# Parse.com JavaScript query error handling does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I'm playing around with the Parse backend and NodeJS but I have a problem right now and I am not able to figure it out. I have a get request like this.

```
app.get("/movie", function (req, res) {
    var Review = Parse.Object.extend("Review");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Review);
    var movie = req.query.movie;

    query.equalTo("movie", movie);
    query.first({
        success: function (movie) {
            console.log("Success");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
});});
```

This works fine but the error handling kinda doesn't. If, for example, I change

```
query.equalTo("movie", movie);
```

to `query.equalTo("movie", "xyz");`

or `query.equalTo("abc", "xyz");`

which does not exist in my table, I'm still getting the success statement. And yes, I have restarted the server every time.

**Update**

I tried the same query using the iOS SDK(Swift) and here I get into the error case. I always get the same error though, which shouldn't be, but at least I get an error while in the JS sample I always get into the success case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe query.first() will not error if it does not find a "first" object. You can check for (movie == null) on the success return.

**Update:**

Try writing it this way:

```
app.get("/movie", function (req, res) {

    var movie = req.query.movie;

    var query = new Parse.Query("Review");
    query.equalTo("movie", movie);

    query.first().then(function (movie) {

        // Success
        console.log("Success");

    }, function (error) {

        // Error
        console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);

    });
});
```

Comment: Still the same result :(

Comment: This is kinda weird. If I change 'var query = new Parse.Query("Review");' 
to 'var query = new Parse.Query("XYZ");'
I still get the 'Success' log

Comment: You can also force an error by doing: If (!movie) { return Parse.Promise.error();}

Answer (score 1):

`query.find()` always success even if there is no match data in your table/collections
Let's try it

```
query.find().then(function (movies) {
    if(movies.length > 0){
       console.log("success");
    }else{
       console.log("query success but no data found");
    }


}, function (error) {

    // Error
    console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that this works but this is not in the sense of error handling. Parse offers some Error codes like 'ObjectNotFound', 'InvalidQuery' and 'InvalidClassName'. I can check these in the error case using an if statement. And I just don't understand, why my query constraint does not work. I mean, if I set the constraint like I did in my post where this data doesn't even exist, I should not get into the success case but I do every time.